# Display katakana middle dot in windows console

Tags: windows, unicode

I got several question marks when trying to print out Japanese paragraphs into Windows console. After looking into the hex code, I find all of them are called "[katakana middle dot](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=30FB)". All other characters are displayed normally except for this single one. After a few google searches, I find [this post](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/12/03/499661.html) saying that this character is a unicode one while Windows may not support it. Any idea to fix this or please tell me it is impossible on Windows.

Here is my related codes:

```
CString file_path;
// ... somehow read the string ...
FILE *fStream;
errno_t e = _tfopen_s(&fStream, file_path, _T("rt,ccs=UTF-8"));
if (e != 0)
{
        cout << "Read failed" << endl;
        return;
}
else
{
        CStdioFile f(fStream);
        CString buffer;
        while (f.ReadString(buffer))
        {
            CString str(buffer);
            // All other characters are fine except for 30fb
            cout << W2A(str) << endl;
        }
        f.Close();
}
```

I have tried `T2A`, `wcout` and `printf` but none of them works.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the output in a Windows console window?  What localized version of Windows are you running, since the console has different font support and encoding defaults.  US Windows won't print Japanese in the console by default, but Japanese Windows would.  What is the result of the `chcp` command?  Also a complete working example that exhibits the problem would help.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  Yes I'm working with Windows console. My windows is in Chinese version and the output of `chcp` is 65001 (since I have set it manually). I have updated the question a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: So your Chinese version uses a console font that doesn't support that particular character.  If you wrote the paragraphs to a UTF-8-encoded file and read it with a GUI tool like Notepad or Notepad++ they will likely use a font that can display it.  Another option would be to change your Language and Regional settings for non-Unicode programs to Japanese, or google how to change the console font to one that supports Japanese.

Comment: @MarkTolonen   Thanks! I tried your suggestion and that character indeed works. However, all other Chinese character becomes invalid. So the dilemma here is that 1) Chinese version doesn't support Japanese, 2) Japanese version doesn't support Chinese and 3) Unicode supports both of them but not this particular character at Windows (see the post I provided in the question: "On Windows code page 932 (Shift-JIS), the default character out of Unicode is still 0x3f, but on the way into Unicode it is (wait for it) U+30fb, also known as KATAKANA MIDDLE DOT.").

Comment: That's the problem with console fonts.  You have to find one that supports all the characters.  I will post an example of printing them both out correctly, but it won't work without a font that supports both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that will output Unicode characters properly to the console, but the console font has to support the characters.  Note that the source is saved as UTF-8 with BOM to support the Unicode characters in the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"ASCII 汉语\u30fb日本語\n");
}
```

Output:

```
ASCII 汉语・日本語
```

Note that on my US Windows console, it displayed as below, but I cut-and-pasted that directly from the console to the above output, so you can see that the characters are correct.

[image]

Here's a How-To for adding console fonts:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/